# Issues casting ElementNSImpl in different environments

Tags: java, spring, casting, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm building a Java + Spring web client that receives an XML and unmarshalls it into auto-generated classes, based on a schema provided by the service I'm contacting.

The auto-generated code contains a getter that returns an `Element` object. To handle this object I cast it as `ElementNSImpl`.

```
public Element getThing() {
     return thing;
}
```

---

```
ElementNSImpl element = (ElementNSImpl) obj.getThing();
element.doSomething();
```

However, I have two available sources for the class `ElementNSImpl`:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl
```

and

```
org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl
```

I also have two environments (testing and production). 
The testing machine runs CentOS Linux 7 and OpenJDK 1.8.0_161.
The production machine runs SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4 and Oracle JDK.

The issue I'm having is that when I ran my code in the testing environment I got the following exception:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl
```

Therefore, I modified my class to import `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl` instead of `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl`and voilà, it started working!
Then I uploaded the same JAR to the production environment and I got the following exception:

```
org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl
```

It seems that each program is unmarshalling the XMLs differently, even thought both codes are exactly the same.

I must also inform that both test and production servers that are being contacted are **not the same**. They are supposed to be identical and behave the same way (according to their support team). Only with different databases.

Could this issue be related to my application? Or maybe it is something related to the file I get from the server? Could it be something with OpenJDK?

Comment: Why do you need to cast it to `ElementNSImpl`? That's internal, can't you work on `Element`?

Comment: `Element` is an interface. 
I use Spring/JAXB to unmarshall the received XML into a class. I don't actually know how the framework does the conversion, but it seems that in each environment it's using a different library to create the `ElementNSImpl` node.

Comment: "`Element` is an interface." - that does not matter. It may have different implementations (or differently packaged implementations) on different JDKs. Why does a specific implementation matter to you? Isn't the `Element` interface not enough for your needs?

Comment: Sorry for the long time to reply. I had to move some sticks to test using just Element in the production environment. The code wasn't written by me and it didn't need any method from ElementNSImpl. I have no idea why the object was being cast but changing it to the generic Element worked out all right. Thank you! Also sorry for not noticing it before posting this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @lexicore pointed out, I didn't need `ElementNSImpl`. Simply changing the target object to  `Element` and removing the cast solved the issue.

EDIT: I still would like to understand what happened there.

Comment: Click and scroll down if you need an implementation example: https://github.com/informationgrid/ingrid-external-service-wfs/commit/7b19457a9a129ab4c2fc07edfce349a5308540f0

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a SOAP response I solved it by importing the following maven library

```
<! - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.org.apache/jaxp-ri ->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.sun.org.apache</groupId>
             <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
             <version>1.4</version>
         </dependency>
```

and in the class where I had to receive the answer amount:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl;
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl;
```

and perform the casting in the following way

```
SERVICEDISPATCHERRESPONSE response;
DocumentImpl document = (DocumentImpl) ((ElementNSImpl) response.getAny()).GetOwnerDocument();
```